# Can't login using omniauth-google-oauth2 resulting you are being redirected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth, google-oauth

I'm setting up a Rails app using [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) with the box [ubuntu/trusty32](https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty32) in Windows 7 32-bit host. The app has Google OAuth login. Gemfile has the following gems for it:

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
```

And in `/config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
  config.omniauth :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_APP_ID"], ENV["GOOGLE_APP_SECRET"]
  OmniAuth.config.full_host = lambda do |env|
    forwarded = env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
    forwarded.blank? ? "#{env['rack.url_scheme']}://#{env['HTTP_HOST']}" : "https://#{env['HTTP_HOST']}"
  end
```

When I try to log in, it stops at this URL seeing "You are being redirected" and nothing happening next.

> `http://localhost:3000/omniauths/auth/google_oauth2/callback?state=xxxx&code=xxx`

I got the following logs:

```
Started GET "/omniauths/auth/google_oauth2" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-10-07 11:07:21 +0000
log writing failed. closed stream
I, [2017-10-07T11:07:21.507524 #2581]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Request phase initiated.
Started GET "/omniauths/auth/google_oauth2/callback?state=xxxx&code=xxxx" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-10-07 11:07:21 +0000
log writing failed. closed stream
I, [2017-10-07T11:07:22.155462 #2581]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.
Processing by SessionController#google_oauth2 as HTML
log writing failed. closed stream
  Parameters: {"state"=>"a6a1e7b1733c564b96ab650f360fbae63cff5bdc6a488f1a", "code"=>"4/D4aX9Bm9XQmSIm_RXBhBi1EXE1AHKp3Q-WVbSpNSdvE"}
log writing failed. closed stream
  Omniauth Load (4.5ms)  SELECT  `omniauths`.* FROM `omniauths` WHERE `omniauths`.`provider` = 'google_oauth2' AND `omniauths`.`uid` = '110281880098696358918' LIMIT 1
log writing failed. closed stream
  Permission::Organization Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  `permission_organizations`.* FROM `permission_organizations` WHERE `permission_organizations`.`domain` = 'gmail.com' LIMIT 1
log writing failed. closed stream
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
log writing failed. closed stream
Completed 403 Forbidden in 302ms (ActiveRecord: 17.4ms)
```

The code is not mine and I'm not a ruby expert too. So I have no idea why I'm stuck at that screen. I also found a controller:

```
class SessionController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def google_oauth2
    @omniauth = Omniauth.find_for_google(request.env['omniauth.auth'])

    if @omniauth&.persisted?
        @omniauth.user.last_sign_in = Time.now
        @omniauth.user.save
        flash[:notice] = 'I signed in with Google authentication'
        sign_in_and_redirect @omniauth, event: :authentication
    else
        #redirect_to new_user_registration_url, alert: @user.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
        redirect_to '/', status: :forbidden
    end
  end
end
```

Here is `config/routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :omniauths, controllers: {
      omniauth_callbacks: "session"
    }
    mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/rails_admin', as: 'rails_admin'

    post '/api', to: "api#post"
    post '/error_catch', to: "api#error_catch"
    post '/error_log', to: "api#error_log"
    get '/file/:uuid/:filename', to: "api#file"
    get '/svg_parts/*dxf_path', to: "svg#part"
    post '/svg/project(.:format)'
    post '/svg/requirement(.:format)'
    get '/svg/test(.:format)'
    get '/pdf/owner_estimate'
    get '/pdf/builder_estimate'
    get '/pdf/wholesale_estimate'

    get '/api/perform_test'

    get '/pdf/requirement'

    root to: "angular#index"
    get '/assets/*path', controller: 'application', action: 'handle_404'
    get '*path', to: "angular#index"
end
```

The information doesn't look enough for this issue? I can also provide more information that may help.

Comment: Let's try this => ```devise_for :users , controllers:  { omniauth_callbacks: "session" } ```

Comment: @RonanLouarn I got the error `Mapping omniauth_callbacks on a resource that is not omniauthable (ArgumentError)`

Comment: maybe you missed to write ```devise :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:google_oauth2]``` in your model @Sithu

Comment: @RonanLouarn Thanks for your answer. In fact, it is a working code in production server. I received the code and setting up in my local dev. I'm not sure I need to rewrite it using user model with omniauthable.

Comment: According to the logs, it results in `Completed 403 Forbidden in 302ms (ActiveRecord: 17.4ms)`. So, I guess SessionController `if @omniauth&.persisted?` condition is executed false and persisting in db seems unsuccessful.

Comment: Why ```@omniauth&.persisted?``` instead of ```@omniauth.persisted?``` in your controller ?

Comment: @RonanLouarn I got it working by inserting a record into the `permission_organizations` table. It should have a record of domain `gmail.com` according to the log `SELECT  permission_organizations.* FROM permission_organizations WHERE permission_organizations.domain = 'gmail.com' LIMIT 1`. The problem is nothing related to Omniauth. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`gemfile.rb`

```
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
```

---

`config/initializer/omniauth.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"], ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"],
    {
      :name => "google",
      :scope => "email, profile, plus.me, http://gdata.youtube.com",
      :prompt => "select_account",
      :image_aspect_ratio => "square",
      :image_size => 50
    }
end
```

---

`config/initializer/devise.rb`

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"], ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"], {}
```

---

`routes.rb`

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'users/registrations',omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks'}
```

---

`controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController  

 def google_oauth2
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Google"
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
    else
      session["devise.google_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

---

`app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb`

```
<%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>

    <%= link_to  omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider) do %>
      <i class="fa fa-google-plus-official fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"</i>

  <% end %>
<% end -%>
[... orginal devise view]
```

---

`/app/models/user.rb`

```
class User
  devise :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:google_oauth2]
  [...]
end
```

---

I hope that will help you!